# Which Open Inventor is in Petrel & Ocean 2012.1?

Tags: ocean, petrel, openinventor

I know Petrel & Ocean 2012.1 release is right around the corner. Hence I am wondering which version of Open Inventor will be used, and where I can find more information about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Petrel 2012.1 will be based on Open Inventor 9.0

** Full documentation of OIV 9.0

oivdoc90.vsg3d.com

** Release notes, explaining what's new :

oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/content/open-inventor-90

In particular please read the section related to .NET API Specific

** Compatibility Notes (.NET specific)

oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/22246#NETAPI

oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/18333#NETAssemblies

** New behaviour of Dispose and exceptions

oivdoc86.vsg3d.com/content/release-notes-86#OpenInventor.NET

Dispose method (since OIV 8.6) raises an exception if the node is still referenced in the 
scene graph. To avoid it, you should first disconnect the node from the children list of the 
parent. 
This new Dispose will also recursively visit the scene graph and call dispose on each node. 
It was not the case in OIV 8.1 (Petrel 2011)

You may also find interesting to read the release notes of all versions between 8.1 and 9.0 
to find out what's new between OIV 8.1 (Petrel 2011) and OIV 9.0

8.5 (January 2011) : oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/18773

8.6 (June 2011) : oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/18867

You may also find interesting to read the compatibility notes of all versions

8.5 : oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/18333

8.6 : oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/18867

Answer (score 1):

Ocean for Petrel 2012.1 will be shipped with Open Inventor 9.0.0.0.

Please be sure to check the [Open Inventor Compatibility Notes](http://oivdoc90.vsg3d.com/node/22246) for version 9.0 and earlier, if you happened to call any Open Inventor APIs directly, because there might be changes needed in your code.

And just a reminder that Open Inventor license is included in the Ocean for Petrel license, but can only be used in the context of Ocean for Petrel. Please contact the Open Inventor vendor, [VSG](http://vsg3d.com/), if a stand-alone version of Open Inventor is required.

More information about Open Inventor licensing, new features and known issues is provided in the Ocean for Petrel 2012.1 Release Notes, which will be distributed with the release.